# Checking whether a type declaration is present for SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I would like to use SFINAE to overload a function template based on whether the template argument declares a type `T`. This is where I was able to get so far:

```
struct C1 {
    using T = int;
};

struct C2 {
    using T = void; // but I would really like 
                    // to not require T at all
};

// For classes that declare T
template <class C>
void f(C &c, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename C::T, void>::value,
                                     int>::type = 0) {
    (void)c;
    std::cout << "With T" << std::endl;
}

// For classes that do not declare T (for now, T must be declared void)
template <class C>
void f(C &c, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename C::T, void>::value,
                                     int>::type = 0) {
    (void)c;
    std::cout << "Without T" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    C2 c;
    f(c);
    return 0;
}
```

How (if at all) is it possible to change this solution in a way that `C2` would not need to declare `T` at all? I.e. I would like to have two overloads: one for classes that declare `T` and one for classes that do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct voider { using type = void; };

template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template <typename C, typename = void_t<>>
struct has_t : std::false_type {};

template <typename C>
struct has_t<C, void_t<typename C::T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename C>
auto f(C& c)
    -> typename std::enable_if<has_t<C>::value>::type
{
}

template <typename C>
auto f(C& c)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!has_t<C>::value>::type
{
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b209c27e6a6d268f)

Comment: Why would this not work with this definition of `void_t`: `template <typename ...> struct void_t {};`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning what type would `void_t{}` have ? did you mean `void_t = void;` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes. template <typename ...> using void_t = void;

Answer (score 4):

You can make a type trait to suit your needs:

```
template<typename Type, typename Enable=void>
struct has_t : std::false_type {};

template<typename Type>
struct has_t<Type, void_t<Type::T>> : std::true_type {};
```

`void_t` is implemented as follow:

```
template<typename...>
struct voider {
    using type = void;
};

template<class... Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

This `void_t` implementation is guaranteed to work in C++11.

Now you can use this type trait like this:

```
template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<has_t<typename std::decay<C>::type>::value, int>::type = 0>
void f(C&& c) {
    // ... C::T exists
}

template<typename C, typename std::enable_if<!has_t<typename std::decay<C>::type>::value, int>::type = 0>
void f(C&& c) {
    // ... C::T doesn't exists
}
```

You need to decay the type as it will be a reference. Since the typedef inside `C` is not inside, let's say `C&`, you must remove the reference first.

Comment: What does the syntax `template<class ...>` mean?

Comment: It means it's a variadic template parameter. It accept any number of type and it this case will always be equal to void.

Comment: I changed my answer. Note that I have no compiler with me at the moment. If it's still not working, leave another comment and I'll check this out.

Comment: It compiles now, but always calls the first version of `f()`, even if C::T does not exist.

Comment: May be it's because I am using C++11... (I did declare `enable_it_t` and `decay_t`)